# How to reset my bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome

When I click on "Other bookmarks", I get about 10 items that say "Bookmarks bar" and another 30 that say "Favorites Bar" and still more that say "Delicious-do_note_delete".

Q: How can I clean up my Bookmarks bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Bookmark Manager**. 

Open it by entering `chrome://bookmarks/` in the address bar or by clicking on the Customize & Control button i.e. `⋮` on the top right corner then select *Bookmarks* and then *Bookmark Manager* (`⋮` > *Bookmarks* > *Bookmark Manager*).

Here you can delete/modify/edit all or desired bookmarks.
Select all shortcut, i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, may come in handy if you want to delete all or most of your bookmarks.

Read more about managing bookmarks [*here*](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/188842?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).